# Is my battery going bad?

Tags: 12.10, battery

I am wondering if my battery is bad, or if I could improve on it. Basically, I am wondering why this image shows `Energy when full: 11.9` and `Energy (design): 48.9` Why doesn't my battery get around `48.9`? Is there any way I can get more information? Can I improve this without getting a new battery?

[image: Battery Info]

Answer (score 1):

If correct, that is the sign of a bad battery.  You can try to fully charge the battery, then discharge ( computer should shut down at around 3% left ), then recharge it to recalibrate the measurement.  The time it takes to do so will also confirm how accurate the reading is.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it seems your battery has reached the end of its life. If it's in warranty, return it.

> Is there any way I can get more information?

Try `upower -d` in a terminal. It's just a little bit more verbose.

> Can I improve this without getting a new battery?

Not really. These numbers are reported by the embedded controller of your PC. It's not something you can do about in software.

#### Recalibration

You can try recalibration by completely depleting it first. Ignore warnings about shutdown in a safe environment such as a Live CD and make sure the laptop turns off by itself. Then recharge it fully again.

Some laptop manufacturers have a calibration tool for this. Not really of any help in most cases, I can tell you from past experience.

Comment: Thanks, but I have already discharged the laptop a few times, and recharged, didn't help, so I guess it is a bad battery.

Comment: I've seen *only one case* in which completely depleting helped a lot. It was running for 40+ minutes or so on **0%** battery. Just ignoring the warnings, it could still run... Then in the next reboot it was showing a much higher "Energy when full" value. :) Later I found out an update to the Embedded controller (with the BIOS release) would also have solved the issue probably.